# In bash, how can I delete a file, whose name was written in a file?

Tags: linux, bash

For example, I have a file "~/garbage_log", the content of it is always change.

```
cat garbage_log
~/garbage/garbage.png
~/garbage/garbage2.jpg
```

now, I want a bash command to delete the file in log,how can I do it?

Comment: Read and pass to `rm`.

Comment: like "rm < cat garbage_log" or "cat garbage_log | rm"?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: @cad ,I tried but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple `xargs` command to run `rm` command on each line of `garbage_log` file:

```
xargs rm < garbage_log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rm` to delete the files and `xargs` to execute  the command while piping the content of the previous command.

You can do it like this:
`cat garbage_log | xargs sudo rm`

Comment: Useless use of `cat`; use input redirection.